# Variable Declaration must appear up front?

Tags: c++, objective-c, c

I'm looking at [this page](http://people.cs.uchicago.edu/~iancooke/osstuff/ccc.html) which says:

> In C++ you can declare variables pretty much anywhere in your program. This is not the case with C. Variables must be declared at the beginning of a function and must be declared before any other code. This includes loop counter variables, which means you *can't* do this:

`for(int i = 0; i < 200; i++) {`

> Forgetting that you can't declare variables just anywhere is one of
>   the most frequent causes of 'it won't compile' problems for
>   programmers moving from C++ to C.

I've been using Objective-C for a while, and thus C, and I have no problems with a statement such as `for(int i = 0; i < 200; i++) {` and yet Objective-C *is* C, strictly, so what is this web page referring to?

Comment: IIRC, that got changed in a later version of C.

Comment: ANSI C is currently C 2011; it allows `for (int i = 0; i < max; i++)` etc.

Comment: `Objective-C is C`. That's not quite true. Objective C is a superset of C and implements additional features not available in C itself. But you're partly right. As of C99, C implements the feature referred to above. But there are still a lot of compilers out there that does not implement C99. The biggest of which is Microsoft Visual C. So for most Windows programmers the statement is still true.

Comment: Your relationship is backwards. C is Objective-C; Objective-C is not necessarily C.

Comment: @Cornstalks "C is Objective-C" is certainly not a valid statement. C does not offer the features of Objective C, it is *not* Objective C.

Comment: @andrewx: I meant "is" as in an ["is-a"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Is-a) relationship. C is a subset of Objective-C (or Objective-C is a strict superset of C). Every feature of C is in Objective-C, which is why one might say "C is Objective-C". However, every feature of Objective-C is not in C, so you can't say "Objective-C is C".

Comment: @andrewx: on second thought, I think we just think differently :) I thought about it more and if I think of C/Objective-C as being sets of requirements, then Objective-C fulfills C's requirements and thus Objective-C is C. Interesting. Well, sorry to nitpick something that turns out to be just different ways of thinking.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The web page is inaccurately characterizing C89.

In C89, you could declare variables at the top of any block (not just at the start of a function), but not at any point during a block.

In C99 and beyond, you are not constrained to declare variables at the beginning of a block.  Specifically, C99 allows you to write:

```
for (int i = 0; i < max; i++)
```

If you use GCC but need to retain compatibility with MSVC, then you can use `-Wdeclaration-after-statement` to detect when you declare a variable after a statement (which C89 does not allow).

Objective C presumably uses C99 rather than C89 as the standard it extends, so it allows variable declarations when needed.